# How to make node express to server parallel request

Tags: node.js, express, asynchronous, request, node-modules

Express in node is waiting until the res.send is called, It is not serving the parallel requests... All request is queued until the res.send for current  request is called...
Is there any way to make the node-express respond for parallel request..

I am making a request to REST end point that take too much time to respond, Meanwhile I want my node http server to serve other request

Comment: Node will do this by default. Please show us your code.

Comment: Sorry My understanding on  node's behavior was wrong.. Now only i got to know my actual problem... My issue is it is serving only 5 request at a time... setting http.globalAgent.maxSockets = 20 is not helping me... Even after that it serves only 5 request

Comment: Sorry Again, The problem is with the browser. there is some limitation on number of concurrent ajax request that can be posted to a single domain....
I just cancelled all unwanted request on page change to make way for future requests..